# Peux-tu me confirmer les PP stp ?

Tags: sens, travail, acronymes

Je viens de recevoir cet email:

```
Bonjour
Peux-tu me confirmer les PP stp ?
Merci
```

Que signifie `PP` ici ?

## Contexte

C'est seulement le second email que je reçois de cette personne (qui travaille pour une centrale d'achat informatique), le premier me demandait le prix total et prix unitaire, délai de livraison, frais de port pour un service de support de mon logiciel. Rien dans ces emails qui corresponde directement à l'acronyme PP.

Rien sur [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/PP) ni [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/PP).

Comment: Peut-être comme *pp* "pages" pour indiquer le pluriel ? Ici "prix" pluriel ? Juste une supposition.

Answer (score 2):

J'ai demandé à la personne qui a envoyé cet email :

> PP signifie ici **Prix Public**.

Les centrales d'achat ont souvent accès à un prix préférentiel, la différence entre ce prix et le prix public leur permettant de prendre une marge.

Answer (score 0):

Travaillant en informatique, généralement les présentations orales sont accompagnées de "slides" PowerPoint (PP). Peut-être la personne demande d'avoir accès au document de présentation.